# Flink CEP - timeout and Dynamic Patterns

Tags: apache-flink, flink-cep

Is there a way to achieve the following with Flink CEP

1. Continue matching pattern of all events have not arrived within time. For example A -> B -> C are supposed to match within 20 seconds, and only event A has arrived, right now I see timeout happens at 20 seconds. After timeout if B arrives the pattern doesn't match.  How do we make sure it continues to match after the timeout has occurred.
2. Multiple timeouts - Is it possible to alert multiple times on a given pattern. I have a use case where in I need to alert at time t1, t2, t3. Is there a way to achieve that ?
3. Multiple Patterns - Is have seen some articles where NFACompiler.NFAFactory is maintained in a map and based on the data, the right one is looked up and used. Is there an example that I can find how to do it with current version of Flink.

Comment: Hey, can You describe the desired behaviour for point 1?? I mean if You want to match happen within 20 secs and A arrives in time but B arrives 25 seconds later than this shouldn't be matched as far as I understand.

Comment: The requirement is when the SLA is not met - we want to alert it out, but also want to monitor the process through completion. Right now if the event B arrives late, the timer triggers and the pattern no longer matches after that. I want the time to trigger, but the pattern continue to match. Should we create 2 patterns, one with timeout and one without ?

Comment: Hmm, technically this is an option but it would results in bunch of duplicates for the messages that arrive in time. How complicated is Your pattern ??

Comment: It is not super complicated. About 10 -15 predetermined steps. Is there a way not to clear the state , that way it can continue to match and the state is cleared programmatically after set time (say a day or so)